# Delete an SQL row with PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, procedure, database-cursor

I want to delete rows by entering the ID hospital but for some reason I get an error when executing the procedure.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE BorrarHospital (codihospital IN OUT NUMBER)
IS
idhospital NUMBER;
CURSOR C1 (codihospital NUMBER) IS SELECT HOSPITAL_CODI FROM HOSPITAL WHERE HOSPITAL_CODI = codihospital;

BEGIN

idhospital := codihospital;
OPEN C1 (codihospital);
FETCH C1 INTO codihospital;
IF (C1%FOUND) THEN
DELETE FROM HOSPITAL WHERE HOSPITAL_CODI = idhospital;
ELSE
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('No hi ha cap hospital amb aquest codi');
END IF;
COMMIT;
CLOSE C1;
END;
```

-

```
DECLARE
codihospital NUMBER;

BEGIN 
BorrarHospital(99);
END;
```

I get this error

```
ORA-06550: line 6, column 16:
PLS-00363: expression '99' cannot be used as an assignment target
ORA-06550: line 6, column 1:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I just started learning PL/SQL and I didn't find how I can solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declare your parameter as `codihospital IN OUT NUMBER`.  That means it takes input *and* output.  So you need to pass a *variable*, something which can take a value.  `99` is a constant, hence cannot be assigned to.  Which is what the error message says.

Fortunately it only takes a small change to the code to correct it: simply pass the variable you've declared but aren't using at the moment.  (I suspect you think you are using it but that's not how things work in PL/SQL).

```
DECLARE
  codihospital NUMBER;

BEGIN 
  codihospital := 99;
  BorrarHospital(codihospital);
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to open a cursor and fetch it to determine if the hospital exists - just go ahead and delete it, then check SQL%ROWCOUNT to determine if any rows were actually deleted:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE BorrarHospital (codihospital IN NUMBER)
IS
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM HOSPITAL WHERE HOSPITAL_CODI = codihospital ;

  IF SQL%ROWCOUNT = 0 THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('No hi ha cap hospital amb aquest codi');
  END IF;

  COMMIT;
END BorrarHospital;
```

Share and enjoy.